# Will Ubuntu 14.04 Have Improved UEFI Support Or Will We Be Using Boot-repair For The Next 5 Years?

Tags: grub2, uefi, boot-repair

Everyday I see questions on here about someone unable to get Ubuntu to play nice with UEFI. They are soon reminded they aren't in Kansas anymore, told to follow the yellow brick road, see the wizard, and ask him for boot-repair. I'm not complaining I understand the widespread adoption of UEFI hardware is new and developing stable software takes time, but I am wondering if any progress has been made that will be incorporated into the new 14.04 Long Term Support release as I've been unable to find any news on this. I did stumble upon some postings about improved Secure Boot support, but I'm more concerned with UEFI support itself than the Secure Boot feature which I don't use.

Comment: secure boot is part of UEFI. And Ubuntu won't be using UEFI, GRUB2 is well aware of UEFI, but the procedure for dual booting can't be made any easier.

Comment: Some computers with UEFI have not needed Boot-Repair with 13.10. Grub2's os-prober has been fixed so you do not need Boot-Repair to fix the chain issue. But some vendors modify UEFI to only boot Windows. That is not per UEFI standard and Boot-Repair has one way as a work around. That can only be fixed by the vendors. The newest grub2 with 14.04 has many more fixes for newest hardware, but hardware also keeps changing and Linux is always 6 months or a year behind major changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't listen to these people. UEFI is a replacement for BIOS, it's been around for years, efi has long been promoted by Apple, and has nothing to do with Microsoft. Microsoft has required manufacturers installing OEM windows 8 to ship with secure boot enabled thus twisting their arms into installing Windows in UEFI mode. This was done to help protect consumers who aren't tech savy, and Microsoft believes if you're tech savy enough to be dual booting you can find the on/off switch for secure boot. If your computer is less than 5 years old you probably have the 1.1 version of UEFI, but the system likely shipped in legacy mode since UEFI wasn't commonly used by PCs yet. As for UEFI support both Windows and OSX have supported it for years, even the IA version of XP supported it, it's not their fault we're not keeping with the times. UEFI is easier to backup and the secure boot option is a big help in the banking industry.

Ubuntu 14.04 will have a beta version of Grub2 that will have UEFI support improvements.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/grub-2-beta-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

Before going to the actual question, I would like to give you an idea of the basics.

The [wikipedia page on UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), gives detail information about UEFI and its use.

> The Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) is a specification that defines a software interface between an operating system and platform firmware. UEFI is meant to replace the Basic Input/Output System (BIOS) firmware interface, present in all IBM PC-compatible **personal computers**.

UEFI is used by windows™ OS's. Skipping the pro and cons, we come directly to **secure boot.**

> The UEFI 2.2 specification adds a protocol known as Secure boot, which can secure the boot process by preventing the loading of drivers or OS loaders that are not signed with an acceptable digital signature.

So secure boot does not allow computers to boot any other OS than the one existing, in most cases it's windows 7/8™ etc.

---

Coming to the question, Linux or any other OS needs to get rid of this blockade, to boot itself into the system. There are few ways to do this, which you can read in many questions across AU. **Ubuntu can't do much to improve this situation**. M$ wants there PC™ to use only windows™, so they make this process as hard as it could be.

**THE TRUTH:** As long as one takes time to read docs, forums, Q&A sites like AU for understanding the process, it is very easy. Just don't mess with either OS.

---

After the [UK OS security test](http://www.zdnet.com/uks-security-branch-says-ubuntu-most-secure-end-user-os-7000025312/) which declared Ubuntu as most secure OS, there were 3 points which stopped Ubuntu from getting 10/10. One of it was lack of secure boot. So Ubuntu has decided to provide secure boot, which will be enabled by default, but would be very easily disable-able.

---

More about secure boot [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot).