# GRUB is still beta after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: grub2

After I upgraded to 14.04 the GRUB still says beta.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 14.04 shipped with a beta version of Grub2. To be specific "2.02~beta2-9".

Sources:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/grub2

[Will Ubuntu 14.04 Have Improved UEFI Support Or Will We Be Using Boot-repair For The Next 5 Years?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439300/will-ubuntu-14-04-have-improved-uefi-support-or-will-we-be-using-boot-repair-for)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:
 1. 'sudo apt-get autoclean'
 2. 'sudo apt-get autoremove'
 3. 'sudo apt-get clean'
 These commands will remove old/obsolete packages from the install. Might have to rebuild grub from recovery also. Use a Live DVD to boot and go into recovery options to rebuild Grub. Other than a few extra seconds on the boot to desktop it is not a huge deal IMHO.